# JSDoc inheriting parameter documentation

Tags: jsdoc

Let's say I have two functions, where one extends the other.

```
/**
* @abstract
* @param {Object} settings
* @param {Number} settings.x
* @param {Number} settings.y
* 
*/
function Base(settings) {
    this.x = settings.x;
    this.y = settings.y;
}

/**
* @extends Base
*/
function Foo(settings) {
    Base.call(this, settings);    
}
```

These two functions are in two separate files. Is there any way I can inherit the parameter documentation from the `Base` function in my `Foo` function, or do I have to write the documentation twice?

I have tried making `settings` a `@typedef` like this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} BaseSettings
 * @property {Number} x
 * @property {Number} y
 *
 */

/**
* @extends Base
* @param {BaseSettings} settings
*/
function Foo(settings) {
    Base.call(this, settings);    
}
```

But this just links to a global Type Definitions, and I want the parameter documented on the same page as the function. But is this even possible, without writing the documentation twice?

Comment: Where exactly is it not inheriting? What do you currently get?

Comment: When creating the documentation in Docstrap, the settings parameter in the Foo function is neither described or links to the settings parameter in Base.

Comment: Are you using any modules or the like or are those really top level symbols? Do you get both documented and what do you get? That the parameter won't get described is to be expected but the type should be linked

Comment: Not modules - in my code these are part of the same namespace, eg bar.Base and bar.Foo. But you're saying, that the parameter not getting described is expected? Well, that's the answer to my question then. I guess it's not something jsdoc can do then.

Comment: Does anyone found something about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. You can document it via `@typedef` as in your question but it will just link the type to its definition. I'm not aware of a way of inlining a defined type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to inline define a subclass but i don't think it does help in this particular case. Anyway maybe it helps others:

```
/** 
 * @defines my.class
 */
function MyClass () {};

var mySubType = /** @lends my.class.prototype */{
    attribute: test
}

var result = myWhateverFunction(myVar, /** @lends my.class.prototype */{ subattr: 1 }) {
   return true;
}
```

This actually should work in any object literal scenario. We're using it in conjunction with a functional driven object inheritance framework (legacy dojo 1.10 declare) where you derive using an object literal within a function call

This way we can properly document the inheritance.