# Ignore "Variable might have not been defined" in specific place

Tags: phpstorm

I have code like this

```
<?php
$first_condition = time() % 2 == 0;
$second_condition = time() % 3 == 0;

if ($first_condition) {
    if ($second_condition) {
        $param1 = 'param1_1_1';
    } else {
        $param1 = 'param1_2_1';
        $param2 = 'param2_2_1';
    }
} else {
    if ($second_condition) {
        $param1 = 'param1_1_2';
    } else {
        $param1 = 'param1_2_2';
        $param2 = 'param2_2_2';
    }
}

if ($second_condition) {
    $param2 = $param1;
}

$total = array(
    'param1' => $param2,
    'param2' => $param1,
);
```

I really know that `$param2` would be defined anyway, but PhpStorm say that it's wrong.

[image]

Is exist there any way to mark this place as ignored of this inspection? Only **this place**, not global settings, and only **this inspection**, not all.

Comment: Standard procedure: `Alt+Enter` when having caret on such warning, find the right inspection, expand submenu and choose "Suppress for this statement" -- it will add special PHPDoc-like comment that tells to ignore that particular issue here. On another hand (especially if it's your code): why not go a bit safer route and just declare those `$paramX` variables with default values *before* the conditionals ... so the variable will be defined?

Comment: @LazyOne I don't add default values, because variable values really differs for any of this condition.

New subquestion: is it possible to disable inspection only for `param1` but not for `param2` using `/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedVariableInspection */`?

Comment: Just define variables with empty values (empty string) and that's it -- variable is defined so no complains from IDE (when it tries to statically analyse such rather complex logic). As for *"is it possible to disable inspection only for param1 but not for param2"* -- No .. as they are both in one statement (array definition) .. and that suppression comment is applied to the whole statement. Split it into 2 statements if needed.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your reply. I'll think on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure -- you can suppress such warning for that statement.

Standard procedure:

1. Place caret on such error/warning.
2. Invoke <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to bring quick fix menu (or via light bulb icon).
3. Find the right inspection.
4. Expand submenu (e.g. <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> using keyboard or using mouse -- note: click area can be quite small -- depends on GUI theme used).
5. Choose `Suppress for statement` option.

The above will add *special PHPDoc-like comment* (`/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedVariableInspection */`) just before that statement -- it tells IDE to ignore that particular issue here.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/suppressing-inspections.html?search=suppress

---

On another hand (especially if it's your code/code that you cane edit): why not go a bit safer route and just declare those `$paramX` variables with default values (e.g. empty string) *before the conditionals* ... so the variable will be indeed defined? This will prevent such false complains from IDE (when it tries to statically analyse such rather complex logic).

---

> New subquestion: is it possible to disable inspection only for `param1` but not for `param2` using `/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedVariableInspection */` ?

Yes and No.

- Without making changes to the code -- No. Those variables are both used in one statement (array definition) and suppression comment is applied to the *whole statement*.
- Yes -- split it into 2 statements if you need such separate suppression.

Comment: Can you say something about [that possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521446/jsdoc-inheriting-parameter-documentation)?

Comment: @PavloZhukov Nothing. Not a JS person myself + have never had a need for that specific case.